# PyQt5: Wipe XYZ Connections

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, ogc, pyqt5

I am trying to remove all the xyz connections in a QGIS3 project via PyQt5. I am hitting the following error for the code bellow:

`for group in getGroupXYZ(self):  NameError: name 'getGroupXYZ' is not defined`

```
 from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings
 
 s = QSettings()
 xyz = 'qgis/connections-xyz'

 def getGroupXYZ(self):
     s.beginGroup(xyz)
     groupsXYZ = s.childGroups()
     s.endGroup()
     return groupsXYZ

 def removeAllConnectionsXYZ(self):
     for group in getGroupXYZ():
     s.beginGroup(xyz)
     s.remove("")
     s.endGroup()

 self.dlg.wipeAllConnectionsXyz.clicked.connect(
     self.removeAllConnectionsXYZ)
```

Comment: How is this code being executed? Are you implementing it in a plugin?

Comment: If this is inside a plugin class, you should change the line which is causing the error to: `for group in self.getGroupXYZ():`.

Comment: Please add other parts of your script. It's hard to give an exact solution. It would be a guess in this context.

Comment: Maybe I am reading this wrong, but just from error message and the code you provided...  getGroupXYZ() is a function, not an object which holds multiple items. the getGroupXYZ() function appears to return an object called groupsXYZ. You should loop over the groupsXYZ variable, not over the function getGroupXYZ().